# Remove Custom List button for only few users of a Profile

Tags: custom-button, delete, list-button

I have a Custom list button which needs to be hidden/removed for those users of a profile who do not have delete access.

There are few users of the same profile who has delete access for that custom object. They should have this list button where as other users shouldn't have it.

Anyone has ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: You would need to either take the delete permission out of the profile and put it in a permission set and assign that to the relevant users or have 2 profiles.

Comment: @DaveHumm  I have already provided Permission set to those users who needs delete access. But my prob here is that The List delete button is available for Users with no delete access also. I need that to be hidden for non delete access users

Comment: Is the button on  list views or page layouts?

Comment: @DaveHumm Its on the Related list of the custom object in Opportunity page layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if the users are all on the same Profile, except by removing the Delete permission from the Profile and using a Permission Set to grant the Delete permission to the relevant users.

The only other way to do this is to clone the Profile and in the new version remove the Delete permission and assign the users who should not be able to Delete records to the new Profile.